# Serialize inherited class with different members MFC c++

Tags: c++, serialization, mfc

i've build a paint application in MFC c++.
All the serialization works for the class that inherit from "Shape". (As ellipse, circle, rectangle).
this is the serialization func of shape:

```
    void Shape::Serialize(CArchive& archive)
{
    // call base class function first
    // base class is CObject in this case
    CObject::Serialize(archive);

    // now do the stuff for our specific class
    if (archive.IsStoring())
        archive << start.x << start.y << end.x << end.y << innerColor << outerColor << thick << style;
    else
        archive >> start.x >> start.y >> end.x >> end.y >> innerColor >> outerColor >> thick >> style;

}
```

This is the function that calls serialize:

```
    void CPaintDlg::SaveScreen()
{
    CFile file(L"FILE.$$", CFile::modeWrite | CFile::modeCreate);
    CArchive ar(&file, CArchive::store);
    Shapes.Serialize(ar);
}
```

and this is the place that the unserialize called:

```
    void CPaintDlg::LoadScreen()
{
    try
    {
        CFile file(L"FILE.$$", CFile::modeRead);
        CArchive ar(&file, CArchive::load);
        Shapes.Serialize(ar);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Some thing went wrong"));
    }
    InvalidateRect(&rect);
}
```

Im holding a `CTypedPtrArray<CObArray`, Shape*> which called Shapes and im calling to Draw func from every index of this array.
I have another class called `FreedDraw` that derives from Shape which have a member that Shape doesnt have which is  member called Points.
(Vector that contains all the points of free drawing on the screen).

In every class i've declared `DECLARE_SERIAL(FreeDraw)`
and in the cpp file `IMPLEMENT_SERIAL(FreeDraw, Shape, 1)`
I have no idea how to serialize and unserialize this vector and how to merge it with my existed serialize function.

Comment: Please show more code.

Comment: added more code

Comment: [Serialization in MFC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6bz744w8.aspx) is mandatory reading. Make sure you understand [TN002: Persistent Object Data Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/32wxt301.aspx) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need something like this:

Writing your `shapes` array:

```
archive << (DWORD)shapes.GetCount();  // write number of shapes as DWORD

for (int i = 0; i < shapes.GetCount(); i++)
{
    shapes[i]->Serialize(archive);    // write shape
}
```

Reading your `shapes` array:

```
DWORD count;
archive >> count;                     // read number of shapes

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
   Shape *pshape = new Shape;
   pshape->Serialize(archive);        // read one shape
   shapes.Add(pshape);                // add pshape to shapes
}
```

Disclaimer: this is incomplete and untested code, just to give you an idea of what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

May you basicly put to the archive size of the vector first, then you can read by a loop with that size from archive object?

Comment: but in my serialize func the vector is not recognized because its not a member of this class